# In the case where $α∈Q$, show that $N(α)=α^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $α$ is an element of $Q[√d]$. In the case where $α∈Q$, show that $N(α)=α^2$.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: What is your definition of the norm?

Comment: It's a field norm, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, but there are several ways to define it.

Comment: The norm is the determinant of the linear transformation $x↦αx$. I don't think this is what you were looking for, but it's all I got.

Comment: A trivial one since $N(a+b\sqrt{d}) = a^2 - b^2 d = (a+b\sqrt{d})^2=a^2 + b^2 d + 2a b \sqrt{d} \implies b = 0 ,\sqrt{d} = 0, b\sqrt{d} + 2a = 0$

Comment: It looks as if there is formatting error, and that's making it hard to understand. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way of calculating the norm of an element in a number field ( your question is about a ring, but you can work in its field of fractions ).

Have a look at this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm.

The second definition states that the norm of an element $\alpha$ in a field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is

$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=(\prod\limits_i \alpha_i)^{(K:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))}$

where the $\alpha_i$ are the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

In your case, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and since the minimal polynomial of a rational number $q$ has only one root (and $\mathbb{Q}(q)=\mathbb{Q}$) you are done.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ has basis $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ then the matrix of $x\mapsto \alpha x$ with respect to this basis is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\alpha\end{bmatrix} $$
which has determinant $\alpha^2$.

Comment: Not necessarily: it is a standard exercise in Galois theory that for any element in a a finite extension $\;E/F\;$ , the norm is $$N(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(E/F)}\sigma x$$ where $\;Gal(E/F)\;$ is the Galois group of the Galois closure of $\;E/F\;$ . In the present case, since $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is the fixed field of the given (Galois) extension, the norm of *any* rational number is the number to the power the extension's degree...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Perhaps you should make your comment another answer.

Comment: It could be the OP hasn't yet gotten to that point so it won't help him a lot. Thanks.